# how to fetch files of user following by user

Tags: laravel-5.7

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower_following', 'following_id', 'follower_id')
        ->select('id', 'uname', 'name');
}


public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower_following', 'follower_id', 'following_id')
        ->select('id', 'uname', 'name');
}


public function files(){
   return $this->hasMany(Files::class)
                ->orderBy('created_at');
 }
```

how to i fetch files of user followig

i have tried this method

```
$file = Files::whereIn('user_id',$followers)
                  ->with('user')
                  ->latest()
                  ->limit(10)
                  ->get();
```

but it shows undefined $followers

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well, you want to fetch files of user's followers.

Have you tried something like this:

`App\User::with('followers.files')->find(1);`